# What does it mean if you are speaking like you are 'delivering a sermon'

Tags: speech, tone

### What does it mean if you are speaking like you are 'delivering a sermon'

---

I recently delivered a speech. When given feedback, I was told the following:

---

> You do have a tendency to fall into a rhythm and intonation that can sound like you are delivering a sermon – be careful with this.

---

What does this mean? I was told my pitch was already very good, so what should I do to address this feedback?

Comment: In actual fact an original, well-structured and well-presented sermon will sound like an original, well-structured and well-presented speech: because that's what it is. Some preachers are less original, less insightful and worse at presenting their sermons; some of them fall into a chanting style with repetitive, aloof and, sometimes, smug overtones more like poorly presented prayers. I suspect that some of that is what your feedback is suggesting that you have a tendency to do. Your presentation needs to be dynamic all the way through.

Answer (score 2):

I associate sermons with a sing-song yet repetitious tone. Difficult to describe so here is an example.

The Most Boring, Ordinary Sermon -
https://vimeo.com/275689798

Note also that sermons are intended to present the *truth*.  There is supposed to be no question that the facts are correct.